# hg unshelve: abort: working directory parents do not match unshelve state

Tags: mercurial

I recently tried unshelving a change on Mercurial, and an unshelving rebase conflict occurred, which I ended up resolving. Something went wrong after that, because now when I try to do anything else, I get the following error:

```
abort: unshelve already in progress
(use 'hg unshelve --continue' or 'hg unshelve --abort')
```

And when I try to use either of those two options, I get the following:

```
abort: working directory parents do not match unshelve state
```

How can I restore my working directory to a usable state?

Answer (score 23):

I deleted .hg/shelvedstate and that fixed it for me. You can also move that file instead i.e. `mv .hg/shelvedstate .hg/backupshelvedstate` if you want to keep the shelvedstate.

Comment: I erased your file, but my extension to show the branch still showed `UNSHELVE`. So I also had to delete `.hg/unshelverebasestate`

Comment: I didn't have these files but did something similar. I moved `.hg/shelved/` to `.hg/shelved2/` (don't delete it, it contains all your shelves!), ran `hg unshelve` (which may or may not have been needed; it reported there were no shelves), and I moved the directory back to `.hg/shelved/`. After that I could start anew.